# Printing program, please explain output

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myPrint (int n) {
    printf("%d", n/2);
    if(n > 0)
        myPrint (n - 1);
    printf("%d", n);
}

int main (void) {
    int count = 4;
    myPrint (count);
    return 0;
}
```

This simple printing programs prints 2110001234, Someone please explain why does it print 01234 at the end. I am not sure why does it add 1 everytime.

Comment: If you walk through your code with a debugger like `gdb` you'll understand the flow better.

Comment: I used debbugger to understand it better, but i still don't understand how could it possibly add 1.

Comment: What do you think should be printed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end you are seeing the calls to `myPrint` in reverse the order they happened.

Here is one way to look at what is happening during each recursive call.

```
myPrint(4)
  printf("%d", n/2)  // Prints 2 because 4/2 = 2
  myPrint(n - 1) // Calls myPrint(3)
    printf("%d", n/2)  // Prints 1 because 3/2 = 1
    myPrint(n - 1) // Calls myPrint(2)
      printf("%d", n/2)  // Prints 1 because 2/2 = 1
      myPrint(n - 1) // Calls myPrint(1)
        printf("%d", n/2)  // Prints 0 because 1/2 = 0
        myPrint(n - 1) // Calls myPrint(0)
          printf("%d", n/2)  // Prints 0 because 0/2 = 0
          // Does not execute if statement
          printf("%d", n);  // Prints 0 because n = 0 at this call
        printf("%d", n);  // Prints 1 because n = 1 at this call
      printf("%d", n);  // Prints 2 because n = 2 at this call
    printf("%d", n);  // Prints 3 because n = 3 at this call
  printf("%d", n);  // Prints 4 because n = 4 at this call
```

Comment: So if i understand it right, this recursive function calls itself 4 times without finishing and then it finishes 5 times with changed value.

Answer (score 3):

`myPrint` is recursive function which is printing the following grammar:

```
myPrint(n) -> printf(n/2) ++ myPrint(n-1) ++ printf(n)
```

for every `n>0`, while for `n=0` the grammar is

```
myPrint(0) -> printf("00")
```

So for `n = 4`:

```
myPrint(4) -> 
-> "2" ++ myPrint(3) ++ "4" ->
-> "2" ++ ("1" ++ myPrint(2) ++ "3") ++ "4" ->
-> "21" ++ ("1" ++ myPrint(1) ++ "2") ++ "34" ->
-> "211" ++ ("0" ++ myPrint(0) ++ "1") ++ "234" ->
-> "2110" ++ ("00") ++ "1234" ->
-> "2110001234"
```

Here`++` denotes concatenation.